# How to augment objects in CGAL AABB tree with custom labels?

Tags: c++, cgal

For a fixed point, I would like to efficiently find the closest item from a (fixed) set of line segments. To this end, I have been experimenting along the lines of the [CGAL example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/AABB_tree_2AABB_segment_3_example_8cpp-example.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_segment_primitive.h>
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef K::Segment_3 Segment;

typedef std::list<Segment>::iterator Iterator;
typedef CGAL::AABB_segment_primitive<K, Iterator> Primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<K, Primitive> Traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits> Tree;
int main()
{
    Point a(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Point b(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Point c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    std::list<Segment> segments;
    segments.push_back(Segment(a,b));
    segments.push_back(Segment(a,c));

    Tree tree(segments.begin(),segments.end());
    tree.accelerate_distance_queries();

    Point point_query(2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
    Point closest = tree.closest_point(point_query);
    std::cerr << "closest point is: " << closest << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, instead of the closest point, I would need to identify the particular line segment (to which this point belongs). If I use for example:

```
auto closest = tree.closest_point_and_primitive(point_query);
auto it = closest.second;
```

then `it` indeed points to the particular segment. However, I would prefer to somehow label each of the segments with a custom id and then retrieve this id/tag instead of the segment itself. Can this be achieved in a reasonably painless way? I have been trying to find inspiration in [another CGAL example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_searching/Spatial_searching_2searching_with_point_with_info_8cpp-example.html), but unfortunately to no avail yet...

Comment: Maybe check the AABB examples that have "index" in their name?

Comment: @MarcGlisse in the end, I am using a modified version of [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/AABB_tree_2AABB_custom_example_8cpp-example.html), i.e., I create a "custom segment" with the extra information required stored directly in its instance. However, it feels somehow a bit dirty...